# MXE - Undefined reference to Qt when cross compiling with cmake and mingw

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, qt5, mxe

I am trying to compile [electronpass-desktop](https://github.com/electronpass/electronpass-desktop/) for Windows using [MXE](http://mxe.cc) on linux. I've already successfully compiled all its dependencies (including [libelectronpass](https://github.com/electronpass/libelectronpass)). Then I executed (from `electronpass-desktop/build`):

- `/home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++ ..` - cmake finds libraries just fine
- `make CROSS=i686-w64-mingw32.static- VERBOSE=1` - make compiles all the project files, but the problem occurs when linking:

  ...
  [  9%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/electronpass.exe
  cd /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/electronpass-desktop/build/app && /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/electronpass.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cmake -E remove -f CMakeFiles/electronpass.dir/objects.a
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ar cr CMakeFiles/electronpass.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles/electronpass.dir/objects1.rsp
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++   -std=c++0x -fno-operator-names -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wchar-subscripts -Wformat-security -Wno-long-long -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Werror=return-type -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -pedantic -O3 -DNDEBUG  -mwindows -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/electronpass.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o ../../bin/electronpass.exe -Wl,--out-implib,../lib/libelectronpass.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles/electronpass.dir/linklibs.rsp
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o):qregularexpression.cpp:(.text+0x2b0): undefined reference to 'pcre2_match_16'
  ...
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.a(qregularexpression.o):qregularexpression.cpp:(.text+0x335): undefined reference to 'pcre2_jit_stack_create_16'
  ...
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.a(qglobal.o):qglobal.cpp:(.text+0x22a): undefined reference to '_imp__WSACleanup@0'
  ...
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.a(qeventdispatcher_win.o):qeventdispatcher_win.cpp:(.text+0x1bce): undefined reference to '_imp__timeSetEvent@20'
  ...
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.a(qcoreapplication_win.o):qcoreapplication_win.cpp:(.text+0x336): undefined reference to 'GetFileVersionInfoSizeW@8'
  ...
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Network.a(qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.o):qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:(.text+0x6a1): undefined reference to 'SSL_load_error_strings'
  ...
  ...
  ...
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Network.a(qnativesocketengine_win.o):qnativesocketengine_win.cpp:(.text+0x181d): undefined reference to '_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
  ...
  ...
  ...
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qzip.o):qzip.cpp:(.text+0x27c3): undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'
  /home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/lib/libQt5Gui.a(qzip.o):qzip.cpp:(.text+0x2870): undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[2](http://mxe.cc): *** [app/CMakeFiles/electronpass.dir/build.make:623: ../bin/electronpass.exe] Error 1
  make[2](http://mxe.cc): Leaving directory '/home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/electronpass-desktop/build'
  make[1](https://github.com/electronpass/electronpass-desktop/): *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:119: app/CMakeFiles/electronpass.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1](https://github.com/electronpass/electronpass-desktop/): Leaving directory '/home/zigapk/Desktop/temp/electronpass-desktop/build'
  make: *** [Makefile:139: all] Error 2

Link to the whole output: https://pastebin.com/v3TiQGk2

I'd really appreciate if anyone could provide any useful information, because I've been banging my head against a wall for the past 2 weeks.

Thank you in advance